# How to fix CSS conflict

Tags: html, css

I do hate to keep asking questions. I have been trying to add code to my website. No matter what code I add, none of it works. I have changed the names of the CSS names thinking that would work but it fails.

Currently I am trying to add in some image gallery blocks. I am on w3 schools and it works.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery

I bring the CSS and code to my website and it looks like this:
https://postimg.cc/image/ifn4dsqrr/

I have tried so many card and block codes and they all either mess up my homepage or ruin the css and I have to revert back to the previous version.

Over the last 2 days I have spent 6 hours trying to get 4 little responsive blocks with image background and text overlay to simply work in between 2 banners.

Here is a link to my test store where I am building out a homepage:
http://newdev-vitavibe-com.3dcartstores.com/

I am determined to learn why. I opened up a request to pay someone to build this homepage for me. I had lots of offers but I really want to learn how myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use bootstrap you could put them in containers, I linked below the documentation for this. Bootstrap will make your life a lot easier when it comes to grids, saved my butt plenty of times.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the html of your site, a saw that what you want could be accomplished with the following html structure

```
<div id="fullWidthBlock" class="fullWidthBlock2">...</div>
<div class="gall">...</div>
<div class="gall">...</div>
<div class="gall">...</div>
<div id="fullWidthBlock">...</div> <!-- all the div.gall where here -->
```

Note that the `<br/>` between the two `div#fullWidthBlock` where removed.
And dont repeat the `id` attribute it is meant to be unique in each html document.

Thats the page with the changes:

[image: Page after changes]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "!important" keyword in CSS. You should use it like that:

```
#smth { color: red !important; }
```